# Error running flutter app in both Android studio and Xcode

Tags: xcode, android-studio, dart, flutter

I am facing this issue after I have switched from beta channel to master and whenever I try to run my Flutter application in either android studio or Xcode I get this error:

```
2018-09-20 15:18:16.711602+0100 Runner[7370:3358571] ../../third_party/dart/runtime/vm/kernel_binary.cc: 39: error: Invalid kernel binary format version (found 5, expected 7)
2018-09-20 15:18:16.711665+0100 Runner[7370:3358571] Dumping native stack trace for thread 9e03
2018-09-20 15:18:16.735476+0100 Runner[7370:3358571]   [0x00000001056f5d64] dart::Profiler::DumpStackTrace(void*)
2018-09-20 15:18:16.735963+0100 Runner[7370:3358571]   [0x00000001056f5d64] dart::Profiler::DumpStackTrace(void*)
2018-09-20 15:18:16.736001+0100 Runner[7370:3358571]   [0x0000000000000000] Unknown symbol
2018-09-20 15:18:16.737556+0100 Runner[7370:3358571]   [0x00000001055f7378] dart::kernel::Program::ReadFromBuffer(unsigned char const*, long, bool)
2018-09-20 15:18:16.737589+0100 Runner[7370:3358571] -- End of DumpStackTrace
```

This is my flutter doctor:

```
    [✓] Flutter (Channel master, v0.9.3-pre.3, on Mac OS X 10.13.4 17E199, locale en-GB)
    • Flutter version 0.9.3-pre.3 at /Users/heyab/flutter
    • Framework revision 8b5af14f24 (17 hours ago), 2018-09-19 15:42:51 -0700
    • Engine revision 2e8e96fad1
    • Dart version 2.1.0-dev.4.0.flutter-4eb879133a

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK 27.0.3)
    • Android SDK at ....
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
    • Platform android-27, build-tools 27.0.3
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1024-b01)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] iOS toolchain - develop for iOS devices (Xcode 9.4.1)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Xcode 9.4.1, Build version 9F2000
    • ios-deploy 1.9.2
    • CocoaPods version 1.5.3

[✓] Android Studio (version 3.1)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin version 24.2.1
    • Dart plugin version 173.4700
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1024-b01)

[✓] Connected devices (2 available)


• No issues found!
```

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Put your `fluter doctor` too.

Comment: Post updated with the flutter doctor

Comment: 0.5.6 is quite an outdated version. You should run `flutter upgrade`

Comment: Just did, thank you.

Comment: Do you still see the error? If yes, please update the question with new `flutter doctor -v` output.

Comment: Now, when I run the app on Android studio, on a Android virtual emulator and actual android device, the app works perfectly.
When I try on Xcode, on a real device connected, it says Build succeeded, but does not show nothing on the screen of the device, only white screen, but when I run it on a Virtual IOS device it gives me:


fatal error: lipo: -extract x86_64 specified but fat file: ....Runner.app/Frameworks/App.framework/App does not contain that architecture

Comment: Post updated with flutter doctor -v output!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have managed to fix this issue: by going to Build Phases -> Run Script and add:
/bin/sh "$FLUTTER_ROOT/packages/flutter_tools/bin/xcode_backend.sh" build 
 and then untick "run script only when installing" -> Code Cleanup -> Build Project -> And perfectly working now! :)